# MVC 4 with jQuery Mobile page seems to be caching and controller method not being called

Tags: c#, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

**EDIT**
Figured it out.. $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); wasn't working because i had data-ajax set to turned off on the form and therefore i wasn't able to set no cache ajax on it.. just for completeness if anybody knows how to get this done WHILE dada-ajax is set to false then please post so here

**Something**  else that I just tried and it worked was to simply add data-ajax="false" to any link that you want a page refresh on. Meaning that if I have data-ajax="false" on a link it will always refresh the page before showing it!

For example the link I had a problem with was

```
<a href="@Url.Action("CreateStatusReport", "ProjectHome")">Add a new weekly update</a>
```

and the problem was that for some reason that page was caching and always showing the cached page.. So one of the easy fixes was to add data-ajax="false" to it and that forced a reload of the page everytime

```
<a href="@Url.Action("CreateStatusReport", "ProjectHome")" data-ajax="false">Add a new weekly update</a>
```

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

**Question:**
I have a options menu which brings up a form which also has a cancel and submit button.

Once the form is submitted there is certain validation that runs and if something is missing it returns to the form with some validation text.

Now if I click the cancel button at anytime i should be brought back to the options menu and if I click on the same button that brings up the form i should see a brand new clean form and this works fine if I do it before the validation.

The problem is that if I submit a non valid form which returns with the error validation messages and **THEN** press cancel it seems that the page becomes cached or something similar because from that point on anytime I click on the form options menu button the same form shows up each with the validation errors and data. I put a break point in the method that returns the form View() and they are never hit so for some reason it skips the entire method which creates a new form and somehow just shows the old page.

The cancel button is the following

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ProjectOptions", "ProjectHome", new { id = @Session["projectID"], remove = "true" })" style="text-align:center" data-role="button" data-theme="e"  data-icon="arrow-l">Cancel</a>
```

Does anybody know what is happening? is it being cached somehow when it returns to the same page with the validation errors??

** EDIT **

I Tried adding `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]` in front of the controller by to no avail..

I also now added

```
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

to the top of my $(document).ready(function () but that also does not seem to be doing anything, do I just put it there or do I have to call it somehow?

I checked System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache and the page doesn't show up there.

Comment: Have you tried using something like Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to look at the traffic to see if your requests are being sent to the server or not?

Comment: just checked and when i press on the button that opens the form after validation and cancel it doesn't show the controller method even running.. it's like it sees the page in a cache and just reopens the old one

Comment: I understood that, what I am trying to determine is if it is caching on the client or the server.

Comment: I am not sure how to check that but under caching it shows "public, no-store, max-age=0  Expires:" BTW I am able to go around this problem by adding a parameter to the controller method.. I thought that maybe it will stop caching if it sees that there is a chance for the data to be unique.. thats a workaround i guess

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the output cache options on the controller action like

```
[OutputCache(Duration=600,VaryByParam="id")]
```

You might also want to try making sure jquery is not caching the request as well. You can globally turn off jquery ajax caching using the information here: [How to set cache: false in jQuery.get call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841425/how-to-set-cache-false-in-jquery-get-call)

Comment: so I see I have to put 

$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});

somewhere and then call it, could you please tell me where should i put it and how/where I should call it to prevent that page from caching?

Comment: What you did in your edit should work if that was the problem.

Comment: The ajax cache false ended up  being what i needed to do.. but i also had to turn my data-ajax back to to true so i guess this one should technically be the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `$.mobile.changePage()` to transition to the page, it allows you to set some options, one of which is `reloadPage`.

> *reloadPage* (**boolean**, default: false) Forces a reload of a page, even if it is already in the DOM of the page container. Used only when
>   the 'to' argument of changePage() is a URL.
>
> *Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html*

You could work this into your link with something like:

```
<script>
function changeMyPage(url) {
    $.mobile.changePage(url, { reloadPage : true });
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="changeMyPage('@Url.Action("ProjectOptions", "ProjectHome", new { id = @Session["projectID"], remove = "true" }))'" style="text-align:center" data-role="button" data-theme="e"  data-icon="arrow-l">Cancel</a>
```

jquery Mobile pulls multiple pseudo-pages into the DOM at one time and normally deletes (`.removes()`) a pseudo-page after you've navigated away from it. It however sounds like that's not happening so you may need to use my above code (or something similar) to force a refresh of the page.

Comment: Hi Jasper I tried that but the javascript function never gets called. I tried putting an alert("hi"); as the first line but nothing. I tried putting a previously made function in the onclick but it still did not fire. Does the anchor tag have something against calling javascript from the onclick?

Comment: I even tried a random <a href="#" onclick="changeMyPage(x)">Cancel</a> to see if its a problem with the button but that still did not fire the function

Comment: @krilovich Now that I think about it, I think that jQuery Mobile strips `onclick` attributes off of elements. You can still do this, just add a class to the link that you can select the element by, then add an attribute like `data-url` that is set to the URL output by ASP. Then you can access the URL via the event handler since it's saved as a data attribute on the link element. `<a class="special-link" href="#" data-url="@Url.Action("ProjectOptions", "ProjectHome", new { id = @Session["projectID"], remove = "true" })">...</a>`.

Comment: Hey Jasper so I did that but the cache still does not seem to clear and the same old page displays..

          $("#special-link").click(function () {
               $.mobile.changePage($(this).attr("data-url"), { reloadPage: true });
           });

Comment: Thank you for your help, up vote for attempting to help me figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your ModelState before hand.

This should work:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) 
{ 
   //saving
   if (result > 0) 
   {
      **ModelState.Clear();**
      return View(new CategoryViewModel()); 
   }          
}
```

[How to Clear model after submit the data in database in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589005/how-to-clear-model-after-submit-the-data-in-database-in-mvc3)