# How to Clear model after submit the data in database in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am submitting some data in database and after submit I want to show same page. But I am viewing the page the textbox value is not empty.

> ModelState.Clear();

I have used to clear the textbox.

But still the textbox value is remain. please suggest me to clear the model after submit in mvc3.

```
public ActionResult AddNewCategory(CategoryViewModel model) {
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    int result = 0;
    var categoryEntity = new Category {
      CategoryName = model.CategoryName, CategorySlug = model.CategorySlug
    };
    result = Convert.ToInt32(_categoryRepository.AddNewCategory(categoryEntity));
    if (result > 0) {
      ModelState.Clear();
    }
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your action code?

Comment: You should not be doing that anyway. If you want to render a new model, then redirect to the associated GET method

Comment: public ActionResult AddNewCategory(CategoryViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int result = 0;
                var categoryEntity = new Category
                {
                    CategoryName=model.CategoryName,
                    CategorySlug=model.CategorySlug
                };                result=Convert.ToInt32(_categoryRepository.AddNewCategory(categoryEntity));
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    ModelState.Clear();
                }}return View(model);
        }

Comment: @MukeshKumar I updated your post with your code. Please consider update your post instead of commmenting your code

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're getting the same model, because you're passing it to the view `View(model)`. You have couple options here: either pass an empty model, or redirect to the get variant of your post action.

**1)**

```
   if (ModelState.IsValid) 
   { 
      //saving
      if (result > 0) 
      {
         ModelState.Clear();
         return View(new CategoryViewModel()); 
      }          
   }
```

**2)**

```
   if (ModelState.IsValid) 
   { 
      //saving
       if (result > 0) 
       {   
           return RedirectToAction("AddNewCategory");
       }
   }
```

PS: I strongly advice to use the second approach as you might want to make other DB calls to construct your model and you won't want to do this in multiple places.

Comment: You still need `ModelState.Clear()` in the first (bad) option.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah, that's true

Comment: The second option uses the PRG Pattern - which is also better as it stops a user page refresh from re-posting the data. As @VsevolodGoloviznin says you also avoid duplicating the building of the model as the get already handles that - so less code.

Comment: Second option is very useful

Comment: Second option is fine, as long as you don't want to pass 'ViewBag' data to the view. But you can always use `TempData` instead.

Answer (score 4):

in very simplest way try it

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)

{

//code here to save data to database

db.SaveChanges();

ModelState.Clear();

}

return view(new CategoryViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1):

[Hear is](https://adevelopersnotes.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/in-asp-net-mvc-what-is-modelstate-clear/) what does ModelState.Clear()

> ModelState.Clear() is used to clear errors but it is also used to
>   force the MVC engine to rebuild the model to be passed to your View.

So as in your case @Vsevolod Goloviznin suggested you can use:

```
return View(new CategoryViewModel());
```

to have view with empty values