# jQuery html() getting Javascript (.js) with ?_=1365695139815

Tags: jquery, html-parsing, autoloader

When I get an url that contains `<script src="some-file.js"></script>` as the follow example:

```
<html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/some-url', function(r) {
        $('#html-container').html(r); // Contains: <script src="some-file.js"></script>
    });
});
</script>

<body>
<div id="html-container"></div>
</body>
```

This is result as sayed before in a autoload from `some-file.js` as result from `/some-url` than jQuery will add `?_={random number}` to query string.

Resulting in the request: GET `some-file.js?_=1365695139815`

How can I disable this random request append from autoload from html() parse?

**@edit**

Since I can't make the request, it's because they are executed by html parse, with the Brian's answer I found this simple solution:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    // Enable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: true
});
```

Found at [How to set cache: false in jQuery.get call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841425/how-to-set-cache-false-in-jquery-get-call)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jQuery appended query string is a result of jQuery's cache busting for ajax calls. To disable this, use the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/some-url',
    cache: true,
    success: function(r) {
        $('#html-container').html(r); // Contains: <script src="some-file.js"></script>
    }
});
```

`cache: true` being the important part.

Comment: Can this option `cache` be passed by `$.get` fn?