# How to force reload page with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

The page I load with .get using the following code is being cached by the browser. How do I force the page to be reloaded each time it is requested?

```
$('.app-ajax-page-content').click(function(){
    var $button = $(this);
    var url = $button.attr('href');

        $.get(url, '', function (data) {

            var $content = $(data).find('.col');
            var html_content = $content.html();
            var lightbox =
            '<div id="lightbox-content" class="inapp">' +

            '<div class="lightbox-content">' +
            html_content +
            '</div>
            </div>';
        });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841425/how-to-set-cache-false-in-jquery-get-call Maybe it cached on server side, so if, then you need to turn off the cache there with the headers

Comment: This one would be the easiest one in your case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8841543/1414562