# the script doesn't reload the loaded php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a webpage that doesn't work fine.
I have this code :

```html
<div id="sc_stats"><?php include_once 'sc_statsm.php'; ?></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $.get("sc_statsm.php", function(data) {
        $("#sc_stats").html(data);
    });
}, 10000);
</script>
```

I want to reload the "div" with the php every 10 seconds.
It only load one time later doesn't load anymore it stay with the same text. The file sc_Stats.php gets a xml that changes automatically.

EDIT : I see it loads every 10 seconds but the problem is it don't post the new text.
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Check console/network tab for errors

Comment: there stands to be too many questions asked here, some of which being as in how you're accessing that file, what is in that file etc.. and errors if any, given you're checking for them.

Comment: What's the error? Could you please explain the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Browser caching? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841425/how-to-set-cache-false-in-jquery-get-call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set cache: false in jQuery.get call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841425/how-to-set-cache-false-in-jquery-get-call)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette this doesn't worked for me

Comment: I don't see any other reason... If it works once, it should work as long as the interval is running. Add a `console.log("Interval ran");` in the `$.get` callback as a test. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, finally I make it work with the help of Louys
I just disabled the Ajax cache

```js
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```