# My updating data in JSON file is not reflecting in my object

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/DisplayMissingTables/json/err_data.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    var jsonfile = data;
    console.log(jsonfile);
  }
});
```

When my json file is updated it still shows the old data. What should I do? I want to display the new data that is updated in the file. Thank you!

Comment: did you have tried using error ? maybe your json is fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET"
      url: '/DisplayMissingTables/json/err_data.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        var jsonfile = data;
        console.log(jsonfile);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

It could be getting cached and this would prevent that from happening: [How to set cache: false in jQuery.get call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841425/how-to-set-cache-false-in-jquery-get-call)