# jQuery GET Function Returns Previous Result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running into a strange problem on my webpage using the jQuery `$.get` function. The code below is executed on page load:

```js
$.get(urls.validateSession, function(data){

     console.log(data);

});
```

I would expect this to make a GET request to `urls.validateSession` each time the page is loaded, then log the response data to the console.

It does this on the initial page load with no problems. But on subsequent page loads, jQuery does not make a new request to `urls.validateSession`. It instead just prints the exact same response data from the previous request (identical response timestamp and everything!)

Interestingly, when reloading the page with `Shift + F5`, jQuery does make a new request to `urls.validateSession` and I can see a new response timestamp.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem if the GET request isn't even sent to the server?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem then? Does your browser's network console show more insights? Is there anything written to your developer console, any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841425/how-to-set-cache-false-in-jquery-get-call) previous question might help get you the desired result.
The JQuery `get()` method's cache is, by default set to `true`.

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')

And it sounds like your results are getting cached, that's why it doesn't bother to run the function each page load.

You can check out more ajaxSettings [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings-settings)

The snippet from @KevinB in the linked question:

```
$.get({
  url: url, 
  cache: false
}).then(function(rdata){
  console.log(rdata);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess it would have helped to do a bit of research into the caching for jQuery GET requests. I actually added ```$.ajaxSetup({cache: false,});``` to the beginning of my JavaScript files to disable caching on all ajax requests.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help :)  Adding `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false,});` is perfect! 

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want caching on any of your AJAX requests, you could also set this field in your initial AJAX setup before running any AJAX functions.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```